# Determining solid region from bounds of triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, solid-geometry

If you have an integral such as:

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{2-x^2}\int_0^{2-x}f(x,y,z)dydzdx$$

How can you determine the equation for the solid region represented by the bounds of this triple integral?

Does this seem correct?

[image: Solid Q]

Comment: Nice confusing y,z,x order :-)

Comment: @GDumphart, of course! Why would it be a common order?

Comment: Well $dzdydx$ would do no harm here ;) I couldn't find your equation btw.

Comment: @GDumphart, for this can you simply rearrange the integrals without changing any of the bounds? I was wondering if that was possible.

Comment: I was just joking around. But now that you ask: Yes, you can write $\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^{2-x}\int_{z=0}^{2-x^2}f(x,y,z)dzdydx$ here since the bounds of $y$ and $z$ both depend only on $x$.

Comment: @GDumphart, does that image I just added seem right to you?